# Undefined Method "attack" for Player::Class

Tags: ruby

So I am trying to make a text based game with classes for an assignment. I have worked for 2 hours and could not find what the problem is.

```
    class Rankuun
    attr_accessor :rankuun_damage, :rankuun_health
    def initialize
    rankuun_health = 200
    rankuun_damage = 100
    end  
    def monolouge
    puts 'Rankuun: "So, I see that you have lived this long. I am suprised.'
    puts "Not a single libing creature has lived for this long inside my dungeon."
    puts "But it's time that your endless slaughter of my brethren are halted."
    puts "Now face what true fear really is!"
    puts "Hoc vanitas est, et non est fere ut serves!"
    puts "You see a mystical aura rise around Rankuun, and hear the shouts of agony"
    puts "Rankuun has grown twice in size, and has taken the form of some kind of lich"
    puts 'Rankuun: WELCOME TO DIE!"'
    end

    end
    class Player
    attr_accessor :health,  :gold
    def initialize
    health = 100
    money = 200
    puts "Health: #{health}"
    puts "Gold: #{money}"

end
def attack
puts "You attack the monster!"
    hitmiss = 1
        if hitmiss == 1
        dmg = rand(5..10)
        puts "You hit the monster, and do #{dmg} damage!"
        monster_health = monster_health - dmg
          elsif hitmiss == 2
        puts "You missed!"
            end 
        end
def guard
    puts "You attempt to defend yourself"
    guard = rand(1..2)
        if guard == 1
            counter = rand(5..10)
            puts "You block the damage, and counterstrike for #{counter} damage"
            monster_health = monster_health - counter
        elsif guard == 2
            monster_counter = rand(1..5)
            puts "You try to guard, but the enemy hits harder than you expected, and you get dealt #{monster_counter}"
            health = health = monster_counter
        end
        end
def loot
    puts "You search the room and find:"
    loot_item = rand (2..3)
        if loot_item == 2
            puts "You find some gold!"
            money = money + 50
              puts "Health: #{health}"
        puts "Gold: #{money}"
                elsif loot_item == 3
                puts "You find a curious potion that seems to heal you"
                health = health + 50
                puts "Health: #{health}"
        puts "Gold: #{money}"
            end
end
def encounter
    encounter = rand(1..2)
    if encounter == 1
    puts "A monster confronts you!"
    monster = Monster.new
    elsif encounter == 2
      puts "There appears to be no monsters in this room"
    end 
end

end
class Monster
  attr_accessor :monster_health,  :monster_damage
def initialize
  monster_health = 50
  monster_damage = 10
end
def monster_attack
  puts "The monster attacks you!"
end
end

puts "There has been a saying in your town for as long as you can remember:"
puts "Ne pas entrer dans le Donjon De Rankuun"
puts 'It means: "Do not enter The Dungeon of Rankuun"'
puts "Many adventurers died inside, and the only living creature in there is the man named Rankuun"
puts "He has great power over the Dungeon, reviving the dead and casting black magic"
puts "You have been selected by the village to go into the Dungeon and exterminate Rankuun"
puts "You have been given a sword, a shield, and some gold. Now you must enter:"
puts "T H E  D U N G E O N  O F  R A N K U U N!"
puts ""
puts ""

player = Player.new
player.encounter
room1 = gets.chomp
  if room1 == "attack"
  player.attack
  elsif room1 == "loot"
    player.loot
  end
```

It would be great if this problem were solved. Thanks for responding and aiding me in my assignment.

Comment: For now, it looks like the problem is in `monster_health = monster_health - dmg`, where you don't have any way of accessing the `Monster` instance. I might use an `Encounter` class as a bridge between them. That way, you could use `encounter.monster.health -= dmg`. However, I advise you to implement the `take_damage` method as I suggested, so that you do not depend upon knowledge of the attribute name.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the exciting world of object-oriented design. Many adventurers died inside.

I think you may have a small misunderstanding about the difference between classes and instances. If so, I strongly advise you to read about it before continuing.

You created a new instance of `Player` when you called `Player.new`. Your first mistake was not putting it in a variable.

Try something like this:

```
my_player = Player.new
```

Secondly, you are trying to call `encounter` on the `Player` class, while you should call it on the new instance.

```
my_player.encounter
```

You do the same thing inside the `Monster` class with `Player.attack`.

I could tell you how to solve each of these problems individually, but I think you would benefit more from redesigning some parts of the project to be easier to change in the future. Hopefully, most of the problems will resolve themselves along the way.

Generally speaking, the shorter a method is, the better. When you tell the `Player` to `attack`, that is all it should do. Instead, it does all sorts of things, including getting the monster to attack!

It suddenly becomes apparent that the two classes have quite a lot in common: they both attack; they both take damage, and they both die. It's time to make a superclass. (If you are not familiar with how classical inheritance works, you should learn - this truly is the perfect use case for it.)

```
 class Character
   attr_accessor :health

   def attack damageable, damage
     damageable.take_damage damage
   end

   def take_damage damage
     health -= damage  # Equivenent to health = health - damage
     potential_death
   end

   def potential_death
     if dead?
       die
     end
   end

   def dead?
     health <= 0  # With random damage, it could be less than 0.
   end

   def die  # overruled by subclass
   end
 end
```

The greatest advantage to doing it like this is you only have to write the code in one place, and it will work for everything. If you change your mind about a design decision, you can change it in one place and know that everything will be adjusted.

You can make a subclass similar to this:

```
class Monster < Character
  def die
    super  # Call the copy of die in Character, in case it contains something important
    reward killer
    puts "You kill the monster..."
  end

  def reward rewardable
    rewardable.gain_money 30
  end
end

class Player < Character
  def die
    super  # Call the copy of die in Character, in case it contains something important
    puts "You died..."
    game.over
  end
end
```

(These are only examples; they are not as complete as the code you already have.)

Do you see how each method only does one thing? If you apply that principle to everything you write, it will become much easier to reuse bits and pieces.

I hope this has been useful. If you decide to stick with what you have and just fix the errors, just say so in the comments, and I'll help you with that.

Good luck!

Comment: After fixing the problem, I get this error:                                                         undefined method `-' for nil:NilClass
(repl):34:in `attack'
(repl):104:in `<main>'

Comment: I fixed up the last code (removing the monster attack from player, etc)

Comment: No, but the error is something about the monster class:                                 class Monster
  attr_accessor :monster_health,  :monster_damage
def initialize
  monster_health = 50
  monster_damage = 10

Comment: Please could you update the code in the question to make it easier to read? Is that the entire `Monster` class?